# How to change the default color of the Command Prompt?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I want to change the color scheme of the command prompt in Windows, ideally a default of `0a` (green color on black background).

How can I change this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open a Command Prompt, click the icon (top-left), select *Properties*.

[image]

Choose *Colors*, adjust to taste. It will ask you if you want to save the colour for future settings - choose yes.

[image]

Comment: +1 You wrote almost exactly the same as me so I just added my pictures to your answer instead.

Comment: thanks.. I should note ths only works for cmd.exe itsef though: if you have a program spawning a console window you have it has the default colors unless told otherwise.

Comment: By the way, the popup colors are used when you press F2, F4, F7, or F9 at the command prompt.

Answer (score 14):

Using the Command Prompt type *regedit* to open the **Windows Registry**, then set the following entry to the color combination you prefer (**DefaultColor**):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Command Processor/
Set DefaultColor to 0a
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer. It's the only solution that works when running Command Prompt as "cmd" in the Run dialogue box, not just from a shortcut. Just goes to show the best answer won't get as many votes without a picture. People like pretty pictures!

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for as well... affects _all_ subsequent cmd calls.  Also worth noting that the first value you enter is the background color and the second is the text color.  Colors are indexed 0-f on the command dialog properties for reference - you can also customize these.

Comment: Great, this works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Go to a command prompt and type `help color` then press ENTER.

You can also select the command prompt icon and change its properties.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the Command Prompt
2. Right click on the title bar
3. Select *Defaults*
4. Move to the *Colors* tab.

Answer (score 4):

```
@reg add "hkcu\software\microsoft\command processor" /v defaultcolor /t reg_dword /d 0xa /f
```

put it inside a .bat file and execute it, or type straight in command prompt
it will make default shell (cmd.exe) color green for current user
to roll back, change 0xa back to 0

ps:

it's based on **ArceBrito**'s answer, i just couldn't comment