# How can I change the Windows XP command line background?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change default color of the Command Line?](https://superuser.com/questions/199764/how-to-change-default-color-of-the-command-line)

In Windows XP the command line background by default is a color. I want to change the background **to a picture**.

What should I do?

Comment: why are you looking for a way to change background? u probably will have hard time reading.... if you are looking for transparency like that in linux, google transparent window cmd.

Comment: Exact Duplicate:  http://superuser.com/q/199764/50086

Comment: I need change to picture