# How do I change the color palette of Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, colors, color-theme, ansi

First, I don't want this: [How to change the default color of the Command Prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/199764/how-to-change-the-default-color-of-the-command-prompt)

**When I say color palette, I mean the real scheme/palette, not just foreground+background.**

I want to change the definition of "dark red", "light green", etc... so the palette shown on the Colors tab of Properties.

Imagine I'm colorblind and don't see the difference between "red" and "green" and I want to change "red" to be the commonly agreed color of "yellow" for example. So any application that prints a red text will actually display as yellow in that command window.

It means that whenever an application prints something in color, the custom palette will be used. Note: I'm already using https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon.
Say I'm running [this program example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor.aspx) and I'm looking for a setting that will make it look different from the rest of the world :)

Comment: So, do you want to change what windows thinks "Red" (or whatever) is, or just what the command prompt thinks "Red" is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Select the box for the color you wish to change, adjust the RGB values for each of the items shown there.

that will change what is Shown on the color tabs, but I suspect that you wish to change all the colors that would also be used in the CMDprompt too?

So far it seems that it does effect the colors assigend via what you can see using `Color /?`  Like Color 1C
Crud, now I have to fix them again :-)

Comment: Holy cow, that works :) And the change is immediate after OK/Apply. (Note: again, using ansicon, didn't test with .NET!)
The process is: set all colors using the RGB and then re-set text/background to what you want, apply and behold. BTW, you color set looks a bittle one-sided ;)

Comment: As a bonus, maybe you know where these are stored in the registry?

Comment: Never mind: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\ColorTable00-15 for defaults overall the system, and the subkeys contain overrides for specific applications with their absolute image path (\ replaced with _).