# How to set the command (cmd) prompt colors

Tags: windows-7, command-line, 64-bit, cmd.exe, prompt

Pretty easy to do in Bash, but, for the life of me, I cannot find a way to change the prompt (and only the prompt) colors in Windows 7's `cmd` window.

Note: the solution suggested in the comments seems to be limited with regard to 64-bit systems. It is *replacing* (*extending*, to be more precise) the command processor instead of playing within the rules (not necessarily a bad thing, though).

Comment: I think it is all or nothing. There is come decent content here that you might find helpfu. http://superuser.com/questions/199764/how-to-change-the-default-color-of-the-command-prompt

Comment: @stephenmuth It is not, see [Color for the PROMPT (just the PROMPT proper) in cmd.exe and PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6297072)

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [Color for the PROMPT (just the PROMPT proper) in cmd.exe and PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6297072)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thanks for setting the record straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297072/color-for-the-prompt-just-the-prompt-proper-in-cmd-exe-and-powershell) in SO, suggested in the comment to my question has answers that seem to be working on my Win10 machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command `@reg add "hkcu\software\microsoft\command processor" /v defaultcolor /t reg_dword /d 0xf /f`. any color also available from 0x0 to 0xf.

Comment: Thanks and welcome to SU. You solution changes the foreground text color of the command console text. I was looking for specifically changing the color of the command prompt only. +1 for the effort.