# Programmatically obtaining color information of a Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, colors

The default color of a Command Prompt window is taken from the Registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Command Processor/` under the `DefaultColor` Key. (as mentioned in [How to change the default color of the Command Prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/199764/how-to-change-the-default-color-of-the-command-prompt)) I can query this programmatically as follows:

```
C:\>reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v DefaultColor

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
    DefaultColor    REG_DWORD    0x2
```

(I had set it to `02`.)

How do I programmatically determine...

- the starting color of a command prompt window? (as in `start cmd /T:7e` which opens a terminal with yellow-on-black; subsequent invocations of `color` will restore the colors to the starting color settings)
- the current color of a command prompt window? (as in `color 2a` which changes the current colors to light-green on green)
- the "reject" color (??? no idea what this is or where it's stored) that you get when you type `start cmd /T:00` which is an "invalid" color setting because in Microsoft's infinite wisdom, it is illegal to have the same foreground and background color, and so you get a different color combination instead, which seems to be the last color combination set interactively from a Command Prompt's Properties -> Color menu, and which seems to be different than the other three colors

Comment: (please move to StackOverflow if you think this belongs there)

Comment: Why? Point two see https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/getconsolecolourexe-prints-current.html